# UIPopoverViewController doesn't return to its original place

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I have reached an issue with the `UIPopoverViewController` for iPad that once a UITextField becomes first responder and the keyboard pops up, the Popover moves to another place, however if the keyboard is dismissed and the position of the iPad is Landscape Left, the Popover doesn't come back to its original place. I had made quite a reseach, also here is few explanations about it: [UIPopoverController not moving to original position after keyboard slides back down](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3537199)

The main problem is that I can't dismiss the popover and retrieve it again, I know this could be a work around but the main project that our team is working on is not feasible to do that.

And few images showing the behavior:

How it does on Landscape right:

Pop up from the button:

[image]

Showing up the keyboard:

[image]

Returning to its place:

[image]

Landscape left doesn't come back well:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use:

```
- (void)presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:view permittedArrowDirections:arrowDirections animated:animated
```

to present the popup in a separate UIView who's sole purpose will be to move the popover around. then subscribe to the UIKeyboardWillShowNotification and UIKeyboardWillHideNotification to animate that UIView, which should move the popover as well.